# No Unity, Desktop Icons (13.10)

Tags: unity, 13.10, desktop-environments

After 3 reinstalls on my Dell Dimension 2400, I can only see the desktop background and the cursor. Nothing else appears.
I have tried removing, redownloading and reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop`.

I have also tried:
`sudo apt-get remove compiz`
`sudo apt-get remove compix-core`
`exit`

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar with my desktop icons disappearing.  Try running

```
nautilus -q
```

This seemed to help bring mine back.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. When I tried this is did not work but it gave me this message: (nautilus:2207): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display